# Test statistic suspiciously low, can this be explained by extremely large dataset?

Tags: hypothesis-testing, t-test, p-value

I have data that tracks purchases and non purchases from an online website. The dataset contains a bunch of demographic features, such as state, age, etc, and also whether or not an individual purchased a product or not.

The percentage of visitors who purchases a product is 68.659%. I want to see if specific features statistically can explain whether or not a customer makes a purchase. So for example if only 11% of visitors from China purchased a product, I would take that to mean that Asians are a demographic group to focus sales efforts on more/market to them more/etc.

This is what I've done so far. I created a function that randomly samples from an array of length 100000, with 68659 1's and (100000 - 68659) 0's. This function samples from that array 5000 times, each time calculating abs((proportion of 1's in the sample) - .68659).

What makes me kind of skeptical is my absolute differences never get higher than .0025. This leads to observed values of even 69% having a p-value of 0. Intuitively, this doesn't feel right. I think it might be because each sample I take from the array of length 100,000, has a length of 280,000+. Still, I'm feeling skeptical.

Any thoughts on my approach?

Comment: What you've written makes it sound like your dataset has 100k points, and you are randomly drawing from it to create one with 280k points. Have I understood you correctly? If so, why would you do this?

Comment: Since the standard deviation of the proportion of 1's in a random sample of size 280,000 is $0.00087665$, your maximum deviation of $0.0025$ is $2.85$ standard deviations.  That's about what one would expect you to observe unless you have repeated this experiment hundreds of times. If this is an unfamiliar calculation, then please review threads related to [binomial sampling variance](https://stats.stackexchange.com/search?q=binomial+sampling+variance) .

Comment: I second @mkt confusion. Why are you resampling?

Comment: Incidentally, I like how you think about your data: in similar circumstances many people have looked at that (hypothetical) low purchase rate from Chinese and concluded exactly the opposite: namely, *not* to market to such people!  However, as others have commented, the simulation you describe seems to have little bearing on this question.

Comment: Re your title: it's not the smallness of the test statistic you're bothered by but the p-value. The title doesn't correctly represent the concern.

Comment: @mkt I guess the reason why i tried this t test was, if for example the feature country didn't have an impact on purchase %, you would expect each country to have a ~68% purchase rate. Now, let's say China has a 62% purchase %. Is that statistically significant as to where I can say 'you should look more closely into China, it statistically significantly affects purchase %', or is 62% something that could happen I guess due to chance?

Comment: @HEITZ I guess the reason why i tried this t test was, if for example the feature country didn't have an impact on purchase %, you would expect each country to have a ~68% purchase rate. Now, let's say China has a 62% purchase %. Is that statistically significant as to where I can say 'you should look more closely into China, it statistically significantly affects purchase %', or is 62% something that could happen I guess due to chance?

Comment: @Glen_b True I guess, but the smallness of the test statistic is what causes the surprising p values, such as the p value being straight up 0.0.

Comment: @whuber Thank you for sharing the calculations, I definitely needed a refresher. So was my methodology in approaching this problem correct, i.e pretty much all the features have an impact on purchase %? That doesn't seem very useful practically.

And in regards to the comment about marketing.. I guess in this scenario, it wouldn't be my decision on whether or not to market more or less. Rather, the 'business team' would just like to know that a person being Chinese makes them purchase at a different rate than everyone else on average. And they can use that information and decide what to do.

Comment: It's difficult to draw conclusions about "significance" from such data, Tony, because they are not a random sample.  Such standard statistical calculations are useful as a rough heuristic to make sure you're not making too much out of coincidental differences.  But when you have hundreds of thousands of data, there's little fear of that.  Concentrate instead on the *practical meaning* of the differences you have observed.  *E.g.,* would an observed difference between a 68% and a 62% rate in some group be large and persistent enough to warrant the cost of an action?

Comment: OK that makes sense. 

And yes, I will focus on the practical meaning of my data. For example if there is a group of a really large size that only has a 15% rate, I think that would warrant a cost of action.

I guess the reason why I made this post originally was I kind of wanted a mathematical way that could help me make the choice whether or not something warrants a cost of action. For a huge difference like 68% and 20%, that difference practically seems large enough to look into further. But for something like 68% and 62%, I'm not sure if that warrants further action.

Comment: Would something like a binomial hypothesis test make sense?